# net/url package adding line feed on request query param

Tags: go

I'm calling Songkick's API, encoding the parameters which are the API key and the page number as follows:

```
    Url, err := url.Parse("https://api.songkick.com")
    Url.Path += "/api/3.0/metro_areas/" + myArea + "/calendar.json"
    parameters := url.Values{}
    parameters.Add("apikey", myApiKey)
    parameters.Add("page", myPage)
    Url.RawQuery = parameters.Encode()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", Url.String(), nil)
```

Everything is fine except that it adds an extra %0A in my apiKey parameter the resulting query looks like this:

    `http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/metro_areas/28714/calendar.json?apikey=myKey%0A&page=12`

I've been following the code in the **net/url** package but I can't figure out why is this happening. The only place this might happen is inside the switch *case shouldEscape(c, mode)* within the *escape* function, but reading the documentation, it should not be my case.

Does anyone have a hint on this?

It only happens when I run it in a *Docker container* based on the image *golang:latest*. If I run it from my local PC it works fine.

This is how I'm reading the file:

```
bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("apiKeyFile.txt")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

return string(bs)
```

Comment: Not reproducible: https://play.golang.org/p/t4j2xZwHFx3

Comment: Most likely your `myApiKey` contains a terminating `\n`. Print it with `fmt.Printf("%q", myApiKey)`.

Comment: @icza I forgot to mention the apiKey only contains letters and numbers, but there are no special characters

Comment: Then please show us an example `myApiKey` value that does not end with `\n` and still ends up in a URL string you posted in the question. Aim for a [mcve]. Because we can't reproduce it, and that makes this question off-topic.

Comment: Show the code that sets `myApiKey`. Random guess: the api key was read from a file with bufio.Reader ReadBytes or ReadString.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @iLoveReflection I'm reading it with ioutil.ReadFile

Comment: Well, there it is.  The file ends with a newline.  Trim the newline with [strings.TrimSpace](https://godoc.org/strings#TrimSpace).

Comment: That was it. If you add it in the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `myApiKey` has a newline and that newline is encoded in the query string.

Fix the problem by removing the unwanted newline. This can be done by trimming leading and trailing whitespace from the the file data using [bytes.TrimSpace](https://godoc.org/bytes#TrimSpace).

```
bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("apiKeyFile.txt")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
return string(bytes.TrimSpace(bs))
```